# unrolling images within cells, MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a structure `face_data` that contains two fields. The first is a 360x1 cell array `face_test` where each cell contains a 88x72 image of a face. The second field is the cell array `label_test`, which contains a label for each face.

What I'd like to do is convert each face image in each of the 360 cells into a column vector - that is, I want to convert `face_test` into a 6336 x 360 matrix where each column represents an unrolled face image. I'm new to matlab though and don't know how to do this without a bunch of looping that I guess is unnecessary. Can someone give me a simple solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple loop should do this fast enough since you know the sizes beforehand

```
A = % .. this is your cell array of data cell(360,1)
B = zeros(numel(A{1}), length(A)); % or zeros(6336, 360)
for i = 1 : length(A)
   B(:, i) = reshape(A{i}, [], 1);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is where Matlab's functions can help. The code is

```
face_data.face_test = reshape(cell2mat(face_data.face_test), [], numel(face_data.face_test));
```

You can easily check if this is what you want by testing this code:

```
s = struct('a', cell(1), 'b', cell(1));
s.a = {reshape(1:9, 3, []), 9+reshape(1:9, 3, []), 18+reshape(1:9, 3, [])}
reshape(cell2mat(s.a), [], numel(s.a))
```